# How to make a Flutter view with an item below a center in parent item?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a view that looks like this in Flutter. But, there is no concept of relative position in Flutter.
Here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

The red rectangle is in the center of the screen, and the green rectangle is right below the red one.

In Android, I can easily do this with Constraint Layout,

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest a good solution to this in Flutter?

Comment: Do you know the height of 2 centered views?

Comment: @PhucTran, both of them are `Text()`. As the text size depends on the device's font style and font size. 
I don't know their heights.

Comment: I added my solution. Hope it help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cynw

Since both widgets are Texts and you don't know their heights until they are rendered, we have to calculate the height and re-render (rebuild) the widget.

In my approach below, I add a SizedBox above the big Text to push it down to make sure it is laid out at the center. The bad thing in this approach is we have to re-build the widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MyStatefulApp());
}

class MyStatefulApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyStatefulAppState();
  }
}

class _MyStatefulAppState extends State<MyStatefulApp> {
  GlobalKey _smallTextKey = GlobalKey();
  double _bigTextMarginTop = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  _afterLayout(_) {
    _getSizes();
  }

  _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed =
        _smallTextKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final smallTextSize = renderBoxRed.size;
    setState(() {
      _bigTextMarginTop = smallTextSize.height;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Margin = $_bigTextMarginTop');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: _bigTextMarginTop,
            ),
            Text(
              'Hello',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 120,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Text(
              'Hello',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  color: Colors.white),
              key: _smallTextKey,
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Flutter [Positioned](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) class is your friend.

A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a **Stack**, and the path from the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image]

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text("Some text"),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text("text here"),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

you can remove the height/width parameter so it adjust the according to the content inside it.

Comment: The big container will not be at the center (vertical). If you provide a large height for the small container, you will see.

Comment: well the big container will always be In center as you can see, there is parameter being provided mainAxisAlignment inside column widget

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you provide a large height for the small container, you will see.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this is: if you center a column and give it horizontal padding symmetric horizontal padding, building 2 Container underneath each other, and position them.

```
home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```